# Is there a built in mechanism for server push on Android?

Tags: android, xtify

Is there a built in mechanism for server push on Android?

What I want to achieve is to start an application based on a server request (without involving SMS, only data connection).

Is this possible without having a service always running?

Thanks
Flaviu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into the framework for this at this time, sorry.

Comment: Thank you.

What about WAP PUSH? Is that based on SMS or MMS?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of 3rd party SDK's which do this, [Xtify](http://developer.xtify.com/notification-web-service) is the one that always comes up.

They have a SDK which you bundle with you app that you can use via a web service to send 'intents' to your app.  The SDK handles the background process and such.

It's free to use up to certain amount of notifications which I can't currently recall.

As for SMS which you mention in your follow up question, WAP PUSH/SMS/MMS all are going to cost you $$$ and have limited applications. PUSH does allow you to specify application handlers via the WAPHeader in my experience it's flaky due to different implementations.